# Why japa samarpan is done in right hand of devi n left hand hand of guru?

Tags: japa

After japa one is supposed to do samarpan in right hand of devi or left hand of guru. Whats the significance behind choosing right n left hand for samarpan ?

Comment: No if the deity is female then samarpan is done to her left hand if it is male then to his right hand.. where did you learn this method?

Comment: @rickross i might have flipped the right n left. But my main question is why different hands are chosen for devi n guru ?

Comment: Well if deity is female i.e for all goddesses, then Japa samarpan is done to her left hand and for male deity it's done to his right hand. This is the rule. So, for Guru also it shd be to his right hand. Reasons probably because male is linked to the right side and female the left side?